# invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId in Mongo DB Rest API

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I am using REST API to fetch data using @Form param from Mongo DB and got the exception: 'Invalid hexadecimal representation of ObjectId'. The syntax seems to be correct, not sure whats going wrong there. I am passing new ObjectId (id) in the rest parameter. The code is as below:

```
//Country.java

package com.speed.infoaxon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;

public class Country {
    public BasicDBObject addDemo(long _id ) throws IOException {
        DB db=ConnectToDB.getConnection();

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("demo");
         BasicDBObject buildList = null;
            BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
            document.put("_id",new ObjectId("id"));
            collection.save(document);
            return buildList;
    }

}


//getResponse.java

package com.speed.infoaxon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

@Path("/add")
public class GetResponse {

    @POST
    @Path("/addDemo")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED} )

    public BasicDBObject addDemo(@FormParam("_id") long _id) throws IOException
    { 
        System.out.println("inside demo");
       Country d = new Country();
        BasicDBObject basicDBList=d.addDemo(_id);

        return basicDBList;

    }
}

Please let me know where is the issue. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: `long _id` does not look like a ["string in hexadecimal format"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) to me.

Comment: I have used int _id, but did not work.

Comment: Because it's a "string". Read the provided documentation. An `ObjectId` is not a numeric value of any kind. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

document.put("_id",new ObjectId("id"));

you're using "id" in quotes which means its id in string you need to pass in the actual id